# Additional permissions are required to access the following files

Tags: ms-office, permission

I have a MS Word document with links to other word documents. Every time I click on one of these links, I get the "Additional permissions are required to access the following files" messages and it is obviously very awkward to grant permissions one by one to many files this way.

Is there any way around this issue? Can I somehow tell the Mac that it is OK for Word to open files?

Update: Word has full disk access permissions!!!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue even worse than you -- I couldn't grant the permissions or open the documents at all. I couldn't open any document created on my Windows computer.

As per [this Microsoft Answers thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/grant-file-access-error-in-word/091aaa12-7831-4b8a-a38d-8099df959f89) I tried moving the cache folder `~/Libraries/Containers/Microsoft Word` to the desktop. Then I tried opening a file that had been working, two times in a row.
The first time gave me a bunch of "can't open com.microsoft.... DFFDF}" errors and wouldn't open. The second time gave me a similar number of "can't create the file ~WRS". Then it stuck on "Processing" for a long time and the fan spun up. Then I killed Word, and moved the Microsoft Word folder back from the desktop to `~/Libraries/Containers`.

After that, all my documents reopened.